# Minimizing surface area for a closed cylindrical can (using variables)

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am not sure how to approach this problem...

"Find the dimensions of the closed cylindrical can that will have a capacity of *k* units of volume and will use the minimum amount of material. Find the ratio of the height *h* to the radius *r* of the top and bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

- volume $V=\pi R^2H=k$ as constraint
- surface $S=2\pi R^2+2\pi RH$ to minimize

Comment: I did that, and I solved for h in the volume equation. Then I plugged h into the surface area equation and set the derivative equal to zero. Is this the right process?

Comment: Yes it should be fine, what did you obtain?

Comment: cube root of (k/(2pi)) = r

Comment: Yes it seems ok now you can evaluate $H/R$ that is $k/(\pi R^3)$ from volume expression, plug in $R^3$.

Comment: Why is it k/(piR^3)... isn't it piR^2 by solving for h using the volume equation?

Comment: Never mind... I found out how to do it and got a ratio of 2! I just used h from the volume equation over the r value that I solved for...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I was struggling on this problem for calc, you're a lifesaver! @gimusi